# Height of a Binary Tree - iterative

Tags: python, binary-tree

This always make only one out while loop:

```
def height(self):
    if self.root is None:
        return 0
    height = -1
    q = self.Queue()
    q.enqueue(self.root)
    while not q.is_empty():
        size = self.__len__()
        height += 1
        while size > 0:
            node = q.dequeue()
            if node.left is not None:
                q.enqueue(node.left)
            if node.right is not None:
                q.enqueue(node.right)
            size -= 1
    return height
```

Do you have any other idea (or idea how to change this code) in order to return the correct height of a binary tree?

len is number of all nodes in a tree, self.Queue is a subclass of class with method height.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What is `__len__` and what is `self.Queue`?

Comment: __len__ is number of all nodes in a tree, self.Queue is a subclass of class with method height.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the information.

Comment: I have already done

Comment: You should also add some explanation about what you intend to do in each part of your code. It took me a while to figure out that you *intend* to "advance" the nodes in the queue by a layer in each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in the part of the code

```
size = self.__len__()
while size > 0:
    # [...]
    size -= 1
```

the number of times the loop body is executed is equal to the number of nodes in the *whole* tree, which is not what you want.

Instead you want

```
size = len(q)
```